# Encrypted mail as user id in GA

Tags: google-analytics

Is it ok to use an encrypted email with public/private key encryption as User ID?

I understand that an autogenerated ID would be valid as User Id, the problem is that because of the complexity of the organization it would take a long time.

Saludos,
Kevin

Comment: You should use a slow salted hash, not encryption.

Answer (score 2):

I have to update this answer, since the paragraph quoted below evidently refers to data imports only.

Googles guidelines on ["Best practices to avoid sending Personally Identifiable Information (PII)" say](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en&ref_topic=2919631):

> You can send Google Analytics an encrypted identifier or custom
>   dimension that is based on PII, as long as you use the proper
>   encryption level. Google has a minimum hashing requirement of SHA256
>   and strongly recommends the use of a salt, with a minimum of 8
>   characters.

I have no idea why this would be okay in data collection but not in data imports, but that's what Google says so there.

**Old answer**

[Somewhat surprisingly that's not okay](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2838984?hl=en).

> You will not upload any data that allows Google to personally identify
>   an individual (such as names, social security numbers, email
>   addresses, or any similar data), or data that permanently identifies a
>   particular device (such as a mobile phone’s unique device identifier
>   if such an identifier cannot be reset), **even in hashed form**.

While encryption is not the same as hashing I'm pretty sure that a ban on hashing will also apply to encryption (after all hashing is not even supposed to be reversible, so in a way it is "stronger" than encryption).

Comment: Do someone know how is that rule verified ? Is Google using some automatic mechanism? list of banned strings? manaul checking by some employee?

Comment: Beats me. It's not like a hash of a random string looks different than a hashed email address. If I had to guess I' say they don't check at all and merely cover their ass by making clear that the responsibility for a potential privacy breach rests with you, not with Google.